# Can you help me with displaying navigation inline (horizontally)?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

My anchor list links are not displaying in-line. Can you tell me why, by looking at my CSS code, or are the problems caused because of my HTML classes?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header group">
  <h1>HTML and CSS</h1>
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="sports.html">Sports</a></li>
      <li><a href="movies.html">Movies</a></li>
      <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Just using li { display: inline-block; }, please refer [HTML Block And Inline] (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp), as you know <a> is the Inline elements in HTML. So when you set li a {display: inline-block;}, it the same you doesn't set display: inline-block; attribute for <a> element. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Use below CSS:

```
    .main-nav li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay so when I type [ li a { ], it only focuses on the a elements?

Comment: When you use li a it will set anchor tag to display inline which is anyways inline element but in order to display list item in single line you need to set li as display inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

You needed to move the `display: inline-block;` from the `li a` selector, to a new `ul li` one.
The reason: The `li` default style isn't inline. As the `li` is the parent, the `li` was on a new line, and then the `a` inside it was inline (which is already the default behavior).

Here is a snippet:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
}

ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML and CSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="main-header group">
    <h1>HTML and CSS</h1>
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="sports.html">Sports</a></li>
        <li><a href="movies.html">Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @BennyLeonard The `li` default style isn't inline. As the `li` is the parent, the `li` was on another line, and then the `a` inside it was inline.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `display` property with `inline-block` value in your css to get horizontal menu. In your code you are floating the `ul` element which is unnecessary but without your html code I can't correct you. Check example below.

```css
/* ul li (I prefer using classes to prevent global overrides) */
.nav-list li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 9px 20px;
  **text-transform: uppercase; 
  /* try adding more styles like borders / backgrounds / colors */
}**

.nav-list li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-menu">

  <ul class="nav-list">
  
    <li class="nav-list-item"> 
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Home </a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-list-item"> 
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"> About Us </a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-list-item"> 
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Contact Us </a>
    </li>
  
  </ul>

</nav>
```

**EDIT:**

`display: inline-block` in `li a` will not work because all the 4 `li` has single anchor element. There is only one `a` element to arrange in same line. Your `li` is closed just after `a`. Hope you got it.